# jQuery .on method needed for element added via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have added an element (a select dropdown) via AJAX, so far so good. Now, when someone selects a value, I want to fire another jQuery event.

I have tried things like:

```
jQuery(document).on("change","#myselectdropdown", function () {
  alert( "did it fire?" );
});
```

and

```
jQuery("#myselectdropdown").on("change", function () {
  alert( "did it fire?" );
});
```

and before that

```
jQuery("#myselectdropdown").change(function() {
  alert( "did it fire?" );
});
```

but none of them are working. I am pretty sure the last one didn't work because the element did not exist on the page when it loaded (later added via AJAX as I said), so I am trying to use the jQuery .on method to bind future events, but clearly I am doing something wrong, because no alert happens on change of drop-down. Any ideas? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: '#' is used for ids; are you duplicating ids when you add your new elements?

Comment: do you call your code in AJAX success calllback function? It seems like #myselectdropdown doesn't exist when you try to assign event to it.

Comment: You are exactly right, it does not exist at first page load, like I said, and so I assume that is why my second jquery is not working. But it does get loaded as an AJAX result and so I was under the impression the way to get around that was with the .on method, no?

Comment: On events will work regardless if the element existed on page load. As long as it exists when the event is fired it will work.

Comment: That is what I thought from reading the jQuery docs, but it is not working for some reason...

Comment: your first example should work to my eyes, the second two are functionally the same. Can you set up a fiddle or something giving more context to the issue?

Comment: we would need to see more from your code :) how do you retrieve the dropdown via ajax, do you append its html to any DOM? etc.

Comment: @DylanCross that statement is not entirely accurate, it depends  whether `on` is delegated to a permanent asset or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies I realize now that I should have posted my EXACT select dropdown name, because it turns out that was the problem. It was named with an underscore (because I had several of them):

```
#myselectdropdown_1, #myselectdropdown_2, #myselectdropdown_3
```

And apparently, jQuery does not like underscores. When I changed my naming to remove the underscore, it started working with the following:

```
jQuery(document).on("change","#myselectdropdown1", function () {
      alert( "did it fire?" );
    });
```

Very oddly, no error was ever thrown, and you would think that would show in the console, no?